# nrwl-Nx and Cypress, verification timing out with failed --smoke-test in Windows 7

Tags: node.js, typescript, angular-cli, cypress, nrwl-nx

I'm trying to follow along with [this tutorial](https://nx.dev/tutorial/02-add-e2e-test) on the NX website.  The 2nd part has us setting up e2e testing with Cypress.  I followed everything as said and even went as far as commenting out my code and pasting theirs into my files.  I'm not getting any errors in the console.  The error I see in Node says

> Cypress verification timed out
>
> This command failed with the following output:
>
> C:.....\Cache\3.3.1\Cypress\Cypress.exe --smoke-test --ping=852

The tutorial also says there's a UI that should pop up on our app, which I don't see anything of the sort.

After generating the workspace and the application it has us modify the `app.po.ts` file by adding a couple constants, so far mine looks like this

```
export const getGreeting = () => cy.get('h1');
export const getTodos = () => cy.get('li.todo');
export const getAddTodoButton = () => cy.get('button#add-todo');
```

next it tells us to update the `app.spec.ts` file of the e2e test by adding this

```
import { getAddTodoButton, getTodos } from '../support/app.po';

describe('TodoApps', () => {
  beforeEach(() => cy.visit('/'));

  it('should display todos', () => {
    getTodos().should(t => expect(t.length).equal(2));
    getAddTodoButton().click();
    getTodos().should(t => expect(t.length).equal(3));
  });
});
```

The version of this file generated by `Nx` comes with this already in it

```
import { getGreeting } from '../support/app.po';

describe('todos', () => {
  beforeEach(() => cy.visit('/'));

  it('should display welcome message', () => {
    getGreeting().contains('Welcome to todos!');
  });
});
```

I originally tried adding the extra test underneath it and added the new imports.  After getting the error message I thought maybe I needed to combine the tests into one test which looks like this.

```
describe('TodoApps', () => {
    beforeEach(() => cy.visit('/'));

    it('should display welcome message', () => {
    getGreeting().contains('Welcome to todos!');
  });

  it('should display todos', () => {
    getTodos().should(t => expect(t.length).equal(2));
    getAddTodoButton().click();
    getTodos().should(t => expect(t.length).equal(3));
  });
});
```

I'm still getting the same error in Node and have no clue as to what I'm doing wrong.  Prior to starting the project I updated `node`, `npm` and `angular cli`.  I downloaded `Angular Console` for `VS Code` but am running into problems with it so I've just been using the Node Terminal and Brackets.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 6):

if you in windows then you can solve this verification timeout issue by navigating to:

```
'C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\3.4.0\Cypress'
```

then just double click on Cypress.exe.
After this close it and go back to your ide or terminal and redo what threw the error

Comment: still has this problem and this still works, after all this time. wow.